# Angular 4 error thrown while trying to use HttpClient with Observable

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to this version of angular and I am trying to implement a simple login using an angular template I purchased online.  I have followed tutorials however when I try running my code the page doesn't even load and I see the following error in my web console:

[image]

Now this error basically has no meaning to me so I have no idea how to resolve it.

This is my **login.ts** file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from "../services/auth/auth.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: '../pages/login.html'
})

export class LoginComponent {

  public credentials: {};
  public isLoading: boolean;

  constructor(public authService: AuthService) {
    this.credentials = {
      email: "",
      password: ""
    };

    this.isLoading = false;
  }


  login() {
    // set loading
    this.isLoading = true;

    this.authService.login(this.credentials)
      .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
}
```

And this is my **auth.service.ts** file:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Config} from "../../app.config";

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  constructor(public config: Config, public http: HttpClient) {

  }

  login(data): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.config.loginUrl.toString(), data);
  }


}
```

I can't tell what is wrong here because everything seems to in order for me, from the error I get the feeling it might have something to do with the promise or how I'm returning or handling the observable.

This is my **login.html**:

```
<!-- pages/login -->
<div class="sample-form-2 login">
  <div class="side-bg-1"></div>
  <div class="side-bg-2 bg-danger"></div>
  <div class="side-description">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="./assets/images/logo-inverse.png" class="img-fluid" />
    </div>
    <p class="text-uppercase text-bold text-center underlined">Warning</p>
    <p>This is a secured system, unauthorized access is not allowed.</p>
    <p>If you landed here by mistake please navigate back to <a class="text-white text-bold" href="https://example.com">example.com</a></p>
  </div>
  <form>
    <div class="form-description">
      <h3>Login</h3>
      <p>Please enter your name and email to login.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Your email</label>
      <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="sli-envelope"></i>
        </span>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Your password</label>
      <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="sli-lock"></i>
        </span>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div class="links">
      <p>Forgot your password?
        <a>Click here</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<!-- end pages/login -->
```

Comment: Can you include your HTML?  The problem may be in there.

Comment: Done added my html.

Comment: Exactly so why am I getting that error in the first place, page loads just fine when I take out the code in login().

Comment: You only changed the code inside `login()`, not anything else?

Comment: Yes I also removed the AuthService from the constructor.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like something is wrong with how you're loading the service in your module.

Comment: I made a mistake with my version of angular, it's angular 4 rather, not sure if that would make any difference though.

Comment: I don't think so.  There were some changes in how Observables work between the versions, but you aren't doing anything that would be affected by those changes.

Comment: Okay I just realize that when I take out the code I am injecting my constructor, Config and HttpClient and remove all code relating to them I get no error.

Comment: It would be nice to have a live example (stackblitz)

Answer (score -1):

Check if your routes are configured properly.I can tell you sure that it occurs due to route misconfiguration.

for eg: in employee/:id route only "employee" could have been assigned in the path